Can an application property be updated/deleted from a ServiceBusReceivedMessage?
I have a ServiceBusTrigger method that processes sales transactions. If the transaction is not found in the database and a 404 is returned, I copy the service bus message and add/increment the retryCounter in the application properties. When max retries is reached, I write it to dead letter.
My issue is that I need a way to either remove the retryCounter from the serviceBusReceived message, or be able to set it back to zero so that the message(s) can be resubmitted.
Here's the logic I currently have in the catch.
`            catch (Exception ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("Not Found"))
{
int retries = 0;
            var parsedMessage = _messageReceiver.ParseServiceBusMessage(message);
            
            // create new sb message and retrieve retry count
            var newMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(message);
            newMessage.ApplicationProperties.TryGetValue("RetryCount", out object retry);
            
            if (retry != null)
                retries = Convert.ToInt32(retry);
            
            // retry less than max count - increment count, submit new msg to service bus, complete previous sb message
            if (retries < _config.MaxRetryCount)
            {
                var msgSuffix = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.FFFFFF");
                newMessage.MessageId = $"{parsedMessage.Transaction} {msgSuffix}";

                if (!newMessage.ApplicationProperties.ContainsKey("RetryCount"))
                    newMessage.ApplicationProperties.Add("RetryCount", (retries + 1).ToString());
                else
                {
                    newMessage.ApplicationProperties.Remove("RetryCount");
                    newMessage.ApplicationProperties.Add("RetryCount", (retries + 1).ToString());
                }

                newMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(_config.HoldServiceBusMsgMinutes);

                await outputEvents.AddAsync(newMessage);
                log.LogInformation("Transaction not found. Resubmitted to service bus {transaction}", parsedMessage.Transaction);

                await _messageReceiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message, messageReceiver);
            }
            // max retries reached - deadletter the service bus message
            else
            {
                log.LogError("Transaction number {transaction} has reached max number of 404 retries", parsedMessage.Transaction);
                await _messageReceiver.DeadletterMessageAsync(message, messageReceiver, ex);
            }
        }

`
I looked for a Remove() method in the ServiceBusReceived.ApplicationProperties, or for a way of updating the properties, but I believe they are read only. Is there another way I can get the message to dead letter without the counter, or at least updated to zero? Thank you for any suggestions.

Service Bus messages are immutable to consumers.  After they are published, the only changes to a message that can occur are the broker-owned fields, such as LockedUntil.  These are dynamically populated them each time a message is read based on the current broker state.
As a result, there's no way to manage a retry count application property in the way that you're intending - unless you're willing to clone the message and publish the copy with the updated value.
For this specific scenario, you may want to consider using DeliveryCount, which is a broker-owned property that increases by 1 each time a message is received after being abandoned explicitly or due to lock expiration.
In fact, if your aim is to dead-letter after retrying some number of times, Service Bus can manage this implicitly for you via the Maximum Delivery Count setting.  Your application would need only to decide whether to complete on success or abandon on failure.  More discussion can be found in Moving messages to the DLQ.

Thanks for the suggestion, Jesse. This was the first time I've tried this and sounds like you have a much better solution. I'll look into it!
